# What is OATHAuthAlias / OATHAuth.alias.php used for in the OATHAuth mediawiki plug-in?

Tags: mediawiki

I am creating a mediawiki authentication module for the SAML Mellon Apache module.

I am basing it on the [OAUTHAuth](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OATHAuth) authentication module that now ships standards with mediawiki.

I am trying to understand why there is a file called OATHAuth.alias.php and what it does. The internal comments state:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Aliases for OATHAuth's special pages
 *
 * @file
 * @ingroup Extensions
 */

$specialPageAliases = [];

/** English (English) */
$specialPageAliases['en'] = [
        'OATH' => [ 'Two-factor authentication', 'OATH', 'OATHAuth' ],
];

/** Arabic (ةيبرعلا) */
$specialPageAliases['ar'] = [
        'OATH' => [ 'ثوأ_ثاوأ' ,'ثاوأ' ],
];
...
```

It's not clear what this means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how special page names are translated. (See [the docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Localisation#Localising_namespaces_and_special_page_aliases) for details.) So internally in the code you would use `OATH` to identify the special page (e.g. `SpecialPage::getTitleFor( 'OATH' )->getFullURL()`), on an English wiki visiting `Special:OATH` would work (it's in the alias list) but would redirect to `Special:Two-factor authentication` (the first list item), while on an Arabic wiki the page name would be `خاص:أواث` and so on.

Comment: Ah, so that the `Special:` special pages appear with localized names, rather than english names. I get it. But `Special:` is still in English, right?

Comment: Usually not; namespaces are translatable with a similar mechanism. But since the `Special:` namespace is defined in MediaWiki core, the translation happens there (`$namespaceNames` and a few related variables in files like `languages/messages/MessagesAr.php`).